# sql zero leading in comparing 2 record set

Tags: sql

I have a problem compare 2 set of data with and without leading zero.
In the Inventory_NBP, there is as 000000000000909120.
However, in PDM_Analysis, there exist only 909120 without the leading zero.
The current query below failed to retrieve any 000000000000909120 or 909120 as the "IN" condition is not met.

How do i modify the query below to fulfill my requirement?

```
sel * FROM Inventory_NBP.v_dmnd_rsrv_dpnd_rqr_mrp
WHERE plnt_id ='WA01' 
and mtrl_id in('G29329-001', '000000000000909120', '13-0006-001') 
and 
 (mtrl_id, plnt_id)
      IN
      (    SELECT itm_cd, sap_plnt_cd
           FROM PDM_Analysis.v_itm_plnt_extn
      )
```

Comment: please update your question with the Table schema definition of the tables involved.

Comment: You could try using regular expressions if your server supports it. e.g. mySQL does: `... and mtrl_id REGEXP('^(G29329-001|0*909120|13-0006-001)$')`

Comment: sorry my server don support this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do casting. This may solve your problem. Please check.

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory_NBP.v_dmnd_rsrv_dpnd_rqr_mrp
WHERE plnt_id ='WA01' 
and mtrl_id in('G29329-001',CAST(CAST('000000000000909120' AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)), '13-0006-001') 
and 
 (mtrl_id, plnt_id)
      IN
      (    SELECT itm_cd, sap_plnt_cd
           FROM PDM_Analysis.v_itm_plnt_extn
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to match values regardless of leading zeros by padding (SQL Server 2008 syntax):

```
WITH T1
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('000000000000909120'),
                     ('00000000099'),
                     ('000000055'), 
                     ('22'),
                     ('152')
             ) AS T (data_col)
     ),
     T2
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('909120'),
                     ('99'),
                     ('00055'), 
                     ('0000000022'), 
                     ('152')
             ) AS T (data_col)
     )     
SELECT *
  FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
          ON T1.data_col 
                = REPLICATE('0', LEN(T1.data_col) - LEN(T2.data_col)) 
                     + T2.data_col
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
          ON T2.data_col 
                = REPLICATE('0', LEN(T2.data_col) - LEN(T1.data_col)) 
                     + T1.data_col;
```